# Accessing other forms variables

Tags: c#, forms

I am learning C# with WinForms and Console Apps. I have a problem with accessing another forms variable. Instead of declaring new Form Objects, I realised that to use the variable from another form, I needed to use the same form instance which contained the variable. After changing my forms, I got an error in the Program.cs file which I cant seem to fix. I am quite new to C# in Forms so Sorry in advance if this is a noob error. Declaring objects of classes is new to me :X

Here is the code behind the forms so you can get a better understanding:

frmOptions:

```
public partial class frmOptions : Form
    {
        frmHelp frmHelp1;

        public frmOptions(frmHelp frmHelp1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tbnDisplayHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //frmHelp frmHelp = new frmHelp();        //Declare a new object for the Help form so it can be accessed
            frmHelp1.bAccessedFromForm = true;
            this.Close();
            frmHelp1.Show();
        }
```

frmHelp:

```
public partial class frmHelp : Form
{
    frmOptions frmOptions1;
    frmLoginCreate frmLoginCreate1;

    public bool bAccessedFromForm = false;

    public frmHelp(frmOptions frmOptions1, frmLoginCreate frmLoginCreate)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //frmLoginCreate frmLoginCreate1 = new frmLoginCreate();
        this.Hide();
        frmLoginCreate1.Show();
    }

    private void frmHelp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bAccessedFromForm == true)
        {
            btnOK.Hide();
            btnReturnToForm.Show();
        }
    }

    private void btnReturnToForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        frmOptions1.Show();
        btnOK.Show();
    }
}
```

This is my Program.cs file:

```
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new frmHelp());
        }
    }
```

This is the error I get in my program.cs file:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'frmOptions1' of 'frmHelp.frmHelp(frmOptions,
>   frmLoginCreate)'

Comment: The only `constructor` within `frmHelp` form expecting 2 parameters and you are providing none, create a `constructor` overload which expect no parameters then there won't be any errors anymore.

Comment: What variables do you need in the other forms? Can you update your code?

Comment: Choosing the same name for fields and parameters, will become a mess. I prefer prefixing the fields with `_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create new instance of frmHelp but not passing any parameters.

You frmHelp class have only one constructor with two parameters :

```
public frmHelp(frmOptions frmOptions1, frmLoginCreate frmLoginCreate)
{
        InitializeComponent();
}
```

The simple answer is to change the previous to :

```
public frmHelp()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

since you are not doing anything with those 2 parameters

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer directly your question, but might help with your solution;

I would prefer using [`modal forms`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of normal forms.

For example:  **(this is just an example to show how it could be done)**

```
public class FormMain : Form
{
    // you might 'remember' the previous login name
    private string _previousUsername;

    private void ButtonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // create the login form
        using(var loginForm = new FormLogin())
        {
            // fillin the previous username
            loginForm.Username = _previousUsername;

            // this will block here, until the loginForm's DialogResult is set
            var result = loginForm.ShowDialog();

            // if the form was closed (other than pressing ok), cancel login
            if(result != DialogResult.OK)
                return;

            // verify loginForm.Username, loginForm.Password
        }
    }

}


public class FormLogin : Form
{
    // wrapper properties, it wraps the textbox.Text,
    // you don't want to expose the textbox directly, you might want to
    // use some other controls in future as editbox, which will change the contract 
    // for classes that are using this control/form, which causes modifying code 
    // on more than one place, (also affects testing again). This way you can keep it 
    // separated. Classes dependend on the FormLogin, shouldn't be dependend
    // on how it is presented.(UI)
    public string Username 
    { 
        get { return textboxUsername.Text; }
        set { textboxUsername.Text = value; }
    }

    public string Password 
    { 
        get { return textboxPassword.Text; }
        set { textboxPassword.Text = value; }
    }

    private void ButtonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

---

**And if you want to pass data to another form, you could use a DataHolder class.**

Something like:

```
// dataholder class
public class MyDataHolder
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int MyId { get; set; }
    public List<double> Whatever { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}

// form1
public class Form1: Form
{
    // a field with a reference to the dataholder
    private MyDataHolder _myData;

    public Form1()
    {
        // create the data
        _myData = new MyDataHolder();
        _myData.UserName = "Unknown";
        _myData.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // create the form2 and pass the data
        using(Form2 form2 = new Form2(_myData))
            form2.ShowDialog();
    }
}

public class Form2 : Form
{
    // a field with a reference to the dataholder
    private MyDataHolder _myData;

    public Form2(MyDataHolder myData)
    {
        // don't forget to assign it to the field
        _myData = myData;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // show the username
        MessageBox.Show(_myData.UserName);
    }
}
```

Now both forms are referencing the same data. This way you remove the dependency from `Form2` on `Form1`. So you can reuse the `Form2` also in other forms, as long as you pass a valid `MyDataHolder` to the `Form2`, it will run. A `Form1` that uses `Form2` and `Form2` that uses `Form1` gives you limited reusability, you'd like to reuse written code instead rewrite it ;-)

---

**I hope this will help you in you quest....**